# UITableView viewForFooterInSection issues when hiding a keyboard swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios-simulator, uikeyboard

I have a UITableView with section headers and footers. In viewForFooterInSection cell I have a two button & UITextView, which triggers the display of a keyboard. While dismissing the keyboard in iPad and tested on simulator viewForFooterInSection cell disappears and leaves a black space.[image]

[image]

This happens only in iPad. Any ideas how I might fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: did you use IQKeyboard library for keyboard? If yes, disable it and check. Hopefully it will solves the problem.

Comment: no, I didn't use IQKeyboard library